# Facebook API FQL multiquery to get actor name as well as ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making an FQL query using the Facebook PHP API, like so:

```
$stream = $this->facebook->api('fql', array(
    "q" => "SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, description, description_tags, type, attachment 
            FROM stream 
            WHERE filter_key in (
                 SELECT filter_key 
                 FROM stream_filter
                 WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed'
           ) AND is_hidden = 0"
));
```

This gives me the user's news feed. However, this will only provide me with the ID of the `actor` - I need the actor's name. (By actor, I mean the author of the story in the news feed.)

I understand that I will need to query the API again to retrieve the name. How do I perform such a multiquery? Using this example, how can I get the actor name?

Comment: See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883661/running-a-join-like-fql-for-getting-a-user-name-along-the-news-feed-posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people's initial reaction would be to suggest a multi-query. However I dont suggest it for the following reason:  It is possible you app can already knows the name of the actor.

Let's say you do lots of these calls to get stream items (one of my production applications does and I've got it coded the way I describe).  What you don't want to do is overload the API and make Facebook unhappy with your app id and start reducing your call limits!!

So, what you can do is cache (using memcached, web application cache, database, or other) the user name (as the name to id rarely changes for a give id) based upon the actor_id.  This is also valuable to find the to/from ids for other facebook fql objects like comments, likes, etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I would be caching the names into a database, but first I need to find them. If that makes sense? When the page loads, this FQL call is made to retrieve the news feed. I am then displaying the result on a page. However, I need the actor name before I can display it. Once I have done a query to retrieve the actor name, I can save it away to prevent further calls.

Comment: Sorry @DMCS, my question was actually how do I find the actor names? That's the part I'm not sure on. And if possible, perform the query as a multiquery, simultaneously with the FQL query above.

Comment: SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid = (SELECT actor_id FROM #query0)

Comment: Right, so how would I perform that query alongside the query I already have? (http://hastebin.com/qanogorobu.coffee) Basically I need to end up with an object containing an array of all the stories in the news feed along with the actor name for each one.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8663836/fql-multiquery-returning-empty-array Look here for an example.

Comment: Okay, now I have this, which gives me the two queries in one array. Great. (http://hastebin.com/yumomunevo.coffee) Now to use them together, should I merge the two queries?

Comment: Not really merge the two queries, but you will programmatically merge the two result sets.  they should be in lock-step, however, just to be safe, use an array search to bring in the user name to be placed into the stream item.